# Just purchased a "rebuilt" transmission. Do these bearings look new to you?

Tags: manual-transmission, f-150, ranger, explorer

Clearly the locking nuts have been reused (which IMO is bad practice, also the stake is in the different location which may indicate the torque is wrong) but to me the bearings look used. They are discolored around the circumference where I would expect new bearings to be shiny. What do you think? The rebuilder said this would have new synchros, bearings, and seals.

I became suspicious when he said these transmissions normally only last 3 years and 30k miles before requiring rebuild, which clearly is BS. M5R1 / M5OD 5-speed manual transmission from a 98 Explorer, these were also used on Rangers, Broncos, and F150s.

EDIT: The transmission was delivered without the extension housing, so the parts below were exposed without any disassembly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can you assume the torque is wrong just by the stake being in a different position - it may have needed different shims to set the relevant pre-load and is adjusted perfectly. Bearings can be re-used if they show no signs of wear. I rebuilt a transmission that had done 100K and only replaced two of the 5 bearings...

Comment: The rebuilder said it would have new bearings - but you are saying that a "typical" rebuild typically will reuse bearings if they are still OK?

Comment: I believe my comment is clear on that point.... However, it depends on the shop, some will change ALL bearings just to be able to say they changed ALL bearings even if some of the other bearings were still serviceable.

Comment: Saying they "can" be re-used is different than saying the transmission is going to be rebuilt and also explicitly telling a customer that the parts will be new. I always assumed it was a rebuild item if the case was opened, but if not, I am less worried about it.

Comment: You did **not** state in your question that the bearings were said to be "new" by the rebuilder. Either you are leaving out details pertinent to the question or are not asking that which you really wish to ask.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you pulled the transmission apart in the first place? If it was still under warranty and there was an issue, by pulling it apart, you've now voided the warranty. If there was no issue with the transmission and you pulled it apart, you've voided any available warranty. You cannot tell (for the most part) if bearings are good/bad from the outside of the race, you have to look at the bearings and the inside of the race for blueing and/or damage. From what I can see, there's nothing there telling me there's an issue.

Comment: @Paulster2 The transmission was delivered without the extension housing, so these parts were exposed without taking anything apart.

Comment: @Solar Mike I stated in the question "...The rebuilder said this would have new synchros, bearings, and seals."

Comment: Ok, so go back to my first comment... I now have the "feeling" that until you get the answer you want you will keep on...

Comment: Where did you "purchase" this? a well-known transmission specialist or one that advertises in the paper and works out of a shed weekends only? Some of the other parts seem to still need a clean - when i have purchased "rebuilt" units they look "as new", but that may be just down to who I choose.

Comment: Believe me I want to just install this thing and feel good about it. If you're saying bearings aren't always a rebuild item, then that makes me better. But it does concern me that I the builder said one thing and did another.

Comment: What was put on the job sheet? What was put on the receipt? What parts were charged for? Have they offered a warranty with it? This is one reason why people have written contracts, because they all remember different things...

Comment: I have it in writing from the manager, luckily this was not just a verbal thing. 6 month warranty. But I think I am going to take my chances and just install it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86820/discussion-between-masospaghetti-and-solar-mike).